# Why the output curve is not smooth?

Tags: numerical-integration

tmr is the output funciton which is a complex integral, and afa is the variable. If gama is a real number, for example, gama=-4*10^(-29)*(1 - Cos[6*afa]), A2 and A3 can be infinity, and there will contain singular points in the output curve. In order to avoid the appearance of singular points, I have added a small imaginary part (10^(-8)) to gama, i.e., gama=-4*10^(-29)*(1-Cos[6*afa])*(1-1*10^(-8)*I). Therefore, A2 and A3 can not be exactly infinity. However, why the output curve is not smooth? Is it because the integral is not well handled? How to solve this problem? Thanks very much!
The code is as follows, and the output curve is attached below.
[image]

```
Clear["`*"]
vh = 2*(1.88 - 0.59*Cos[Pi/(1 + d1/(0.65*10^(-9)))]);
u = vh*0.89;
mu = 4.6;
gama = -4*10^(-29)*(1 - Cos[6*afa])*(1 - 1*10^(-8)*I);
d1 = 1.95*10^(-9);
d2 = 1.95*10^(-9);
HBAR = 1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897*10^(-31);
ELEC = 1.60217733*10^(-19);
Kh = 2.29*10^(10);
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2];
k := kc*Sqrt[mu]

k0 := Sqrt[k^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2]
kh := Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2]
khg := Sqrt[
  k^2 - (2*Kh*Sin[afa/2]*Sin[afa/2] - 
      k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (2*Kh*Sin[afa/2]*Cos[afa/2] + 
      k Sin[x] Sin[y])^2]
kg1 := Sqrt[
  k^2 - (Kh*Cos[Pi/3 - afa] - 
      k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (Kh*Sin[Pi/3 - afa] + k Sin[x] Sin[y])^2]
kg2 := Sqrt[
  k^2 - (Kh*Cos[afa] - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (k Sin[x] Sin[y] - 
      Kh*Sin[afa])^2]

k0pl := Sqrt[k^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 + kc^2 vh - kc^2*u]
k0mi := Sqrt[k^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 - kc^2 vh - kc^2*u]
khpl := Sqrt[
  k^2 - (Kh - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2 + kc^2 vh - 
   kc^2*u]
khmi := Sqrt[
  k^2 - (Kh - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2 - kc^2 vh - 
   kc^2*u]

k0plpl := Sqrt[k^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 + 2*kc^2 vh]
k0mimi := Sqrt[k^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 - 2*kc^2 vh]
khplpl := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2 + 
   2*kc^2 vh]
khmimi := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - k^2 Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2 - 
   2*kc^2 vh]
khgplpl := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (2*Kh*Sin[afa/2]*Sin[afa/2] - 
      k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (2*Kh*Sin[afa/2]*Cos[afa/2] + 
      k Sin[x] Sin[y])^2 + 2*kc^2 vh]
khgmimi := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (2*Kh*Sin[afa/2]*Sin[afa/2] - 
      k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (2*Kh*Sin[afa/2]*Cos[afa/2] + 
      k Sin[x] Sin[y])^2 - 2*kc^2 vh]
kg1plpl := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh*Cos[Pi/3 - afa] - 
      k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (Kh*Sin[Pi/3 - afa] + k Sin[x] Sin[y])^2 + 
   2*kc^2 vh]
kg1mimi := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh*Cos[Pi/3 - afa] - 
      k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (Kh*Sin[Pi/3 - afa] + k Sin[x] Sin[y])^2 - 
   2*kc^2 vh]
kg2plpl := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh*Cos[afa] - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (k Sin[x] Sin[y] - 
      Kh*Sin[afa])^2 + 2*kc^2 vh]
kg2mimi := 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Kh*Cos[afa] - k Sin[x] Cos[y])^2 - (k Sin[x] Sin[y] - 
      Kh*Sin[afa])^2 - 2*kc^2 vh]

A1 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*k0pl))*Exp[I*k0pl*d1]/2
B1 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*k0pl))*Exp[I*k0pl*d1]/2
A2 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*khpl))*Exp[I*khpl*d1]/2
B2 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*khpl))*Exp[I*khpl*d1]/2
A3 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*k0mi))*Exp[I*k0mi*d1]/2
B3 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*k0mi))*Exp[I*k0mi*d1]/2
A4 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*khmi))*Exp[I*khmi*d1]/2
B4 := 1/(1 + I*ME*gama/(HBAR^2*khmi))*Exp[I*khmi*d1]/2

T1 := 1/4 Re[
    Abs[A1]^2*k0plpl*Exp[I*(k0plpl - Conjugate[k0plpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[A1]^2*kg1plpl*Exp[I*(kg1plpl - Conjugate[kg1plpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[A2]^2*khplpl*Exp[I*(khplpl - Conjugate[khplpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[A2]^2*khgplpl*Exp[I*(khgplpl - Conjugate[khgplpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[B3]^2*k0mimi*Exp[I*(k0mimi - Conjugate[k0mimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B3]^2*kg1mimi*Exp[I*(kg1mimi - Conjugate[kg1mimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B4]^2*khmimi*Exp[I*(khmimi - Conjugate[khmimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B4]^2*khgmimi*Exp[I*(khgmimi - Conjugate[khgmimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B1 + A3]^2*k0*Exp[I*(k0 - Conjugate[k0])*d2] + 
     Abs[B1 - A3]^2*kg1*Exp[I*(kg1 - Conjugate[kg1])*d2] + 
     Abs[A4 - B2]^2*kh*Exp[I*(kh - Conjugate[kh])*d2] + 
     Abs[A4 + B2]^2*khg*Exp[I*(khg - Conjugate[khg])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A1]*B3*k0mimi*Exp[I*(k0mimi - Conjugate[k0plpl])*d2] + 
     A1*Conjugate[B3]*k0plpl*Exp[I*(k0plpl - Conjugate[k0mimi])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A1]*(B1 + A3)*k0*Exp[I*(k0 - Conjugate[k0plpl])*d2] + 
     A1*Conjugate[B1 + A3]*k0plpl*Exp[I*(k0plpl - Conjugate[k0])*d2] +
      Conjugate[B3]*(B1 + A3)*k0*Exp[I*(k0 - Conjugate[k0mimi])*d2] + 
     B3*Conjugate[B1 + A3]*k0mimi*Exp[I*(k0mimi - Conjugate[k0])*d2] -
      Conjugate[A1]*B3*kg1mimi*
      Exp[I*(kg1mimi - Conjugate[kg1plpl])*d2] - 
     A1*Conjugate[B3]*kg1plpl*
      Exp[I*(kg1plpl - Conjugate[kg1mimi])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A1]*(A3 - B1)*kg1*
      Exp[I*(kg1 - Conjugate[kg1plpl])*d2] + 
     A1*Conjugate[A3 - B1]*kg1plpl*
      Exp[I*(kg1plpl - Conjugate[kg1])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[B3]*(B1 - A3)*kg1*
      Exp[I*(kg1 - Conjugate[kg1mimi])*d2] + 
     B3*Conjugate[B1 - A3]*kg1mimi*
      Exp[I*(kg1mimi - Conjugate[kg1])*d2] - 
     Conjugate[A2]*B4*khmimi*Exp[I*(khmimi - Conjugate[khplpl])*d2] - 
     A2*Conjugate[B4]*khplpl*Exp[I*(khplpl - Conjugate[khmimi])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A2]*(B2 - A4)*kh*Exp[I*(kh - Conjugate[khplpl])*d2] + 
     A2*Conjugate[B2 - A4]*khplpl*Exp[I*(khplpl - Conjugate[kh])*d2] +
      Conjugate[B4]*(A4 - B2)*kh*Exp[I*(kh - Conjugate[khmimi])*d2] + 
     B4*Conjugate[A4 - B2]*khmimi*Exp[I*(khmimi - Conjugate[kh])*d2] +
      Conjugate[A2]*B4*khgmimi*
      Exp[I*(khgmimi - Conjugate[khgplpl])*d2] + 
     A2*Conjugate[B4]*khgplpl*
      Exp[I*(khgplpl - Conjugate[khgmimi])*d2] - 
     Conjugate[A2]*(A4 + B2)*khg*
      Exp[I*(khg - Conjugate[khgplpl])*d2] - 
     A2*Conjugate[A4 + B2]*khgplpl*
      Exp[I*(khgplpl - Conjugate[khg])*d2] - 
     Conjugate[B4]*(A4 + B2)*khg*
      Exp[I*(khg - Conjugate[khgmimi])*d2] - 
     B4*Conjugate[A4 + B2]*khgmimi*
      Exp[I*(khgmimi - Conjugate[khg])*d2]];

T2 := 1/4 Re[
    Abs[A1]^2*k0plpl*Exp[I*(k0plpl - Conjugate[k0plpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[A1]^2*kg2plpl*Exp[I*(kg2plpl - Conjugate[kg2plpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[A2]^2*khplpl*Exp[I*(khplpl - Conjugate[khplpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[A2]^2*khgplpl*Exp[I*(khgplpl - Conjugate[khgplpl])*d2] + 
     Abs[B3]^2*k0mimi*Exp[I*(k0mimi - Conjugate[k0mimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B3]^2*kg2mimi*Exp[I*(kg2mimi - Conjugate[kg2mimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B4]^2*khmimi*Exp[I*(khmimi - Conjugate[khmimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B4]^2*khgmimi*Exp[I*(khgmimi - Conjugate[khgmimi])*d2] + 
     Abs[B1 + A3]^2*k0*Exp[I*(k0 - Conjugate[k0])*d2] + 
     Abs[B1 - A3]^2*kg2*Exp[I*(kg2 - Conjugate[kg2])*d2] + 
     Abs[A4 - B2]^2*kh*Exp[I*(kh - Conjugate[kh])*d2] + 
     Abs[A4 + B2]^2*khg*Exp[I*(khg - Conjugate[khg])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A1]*B3*k0mimi*Exp[I*(k0mimi - Conjugate[k0plpl])*d2] + 
     A1*Conjugate[B3]*k0plpl*Exp[I*(k0plpl - Conjugate[k0mimi])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A1]*(B1 + A3)*k0*Exp[I*(k0 - Conjugate[k0plpl])*d2] + 
     A1*Conjugate[B1 + A3]*k0plpl*Exp[I*(k0plpl - Conjugate[k0])*d2] +
      Conjugate[B3]*(B1 + A3)*k0*Exp[I*(k0 - Conjugate[k0mimi])*d2] + 
     B3*Conjugate[B1 + A3]*k0mimi*Exp[I*(k0mimi - Conjugate[k0])*d2] -
      Conjugate[A1]*B3*kg2mimi*
      Exp[I*(kg2mimi - Conjugate[kg2plpl])*d2] - 
     A1*Conjugate[B3]*kg2plpl*
      Exp[I*(kg2plpl - Conjugate[kg2mimi])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A1]*(A3 - B1)*kg2*
      Exp[I*(kg2 - Conjugate[kg2plpl])*d2] + 
     A1*Conjugate[A3 - B1]*kg2plpl*
      Exp[I*(kg2plpl - Conjugate[kg2])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[B3]*(B1 - A3)*kg2*
      Exp[I*(kg2 - Conjugate[kg2mimi])*d2] + 
     B3*Conjugate[B1 - A3]*kg2mimi*
      Exp[I*(kg2mimi - Conjugate[kg2])*d2] - 
     Conjugate[A2]*B4*khmimi*Exp[I*(khmimi - Conjugate[khplpl])*d2] - 
     A2*Conjugate[B4]*khplpl*Exp[I*(khplpl - Conjugate[khmimi])*d2] + 
     Conjugate[A2]*(B2 - A4)*kh*Exp[I*(kh - Conjugate[khplpl])*d2] + 
     A2*Conjugate[B2 - A4]*khplpl*Exp[I*(khplpl - Conjugate[kh])*d2] +
      Conjugate[B4]*(A4 - B2)*kh*Exp[I*(kh - Conjugate[khmimi])*d2] + 
     B4*Conjugate[A4 - B2]*khmimi*Exp[I*(khmimi - Conjugate[kh])*d2] +
      Conjugate[A2]*B4*khgmimi*
      Exp[I*(khgmimi - Conjugate[khgplpl])*d2] + 
     A2*Conjugate[B4]*khgplpl*
      Exp[I*(khgplpl - Conjugate[khgmimi])*d2] - 
     Conjugate[A2]*(A4 + B2)*khg*
      Exp[I*(khg - Conjugate[khgplpl])*d2] - 
     A2*Conjugate[A4 + B2]*khgplpl*
      Exp[I*(khgplpl - Conjugate[khg])*d2] - 
     Conjugate[B4]*(A4 + B2)*khg*
      Exp[I*(khg - Conjugate[khgmimi])*d2] - 
     B4*Conjugate[A4 + B2]*khgmimi*
      Exp[I*(khgmimi - Conjugate[khg])*d2]];

G := Re[NIntegrate[
     k Sin[x] T1, {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/6, -Pi/6 + afa}] + 
    NIntegrate[k Sin[x] T2, {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/6 + afa, Pi/6}]];
tmr := {afa, G};
 Export["D://ceshi.txt", Table[tmr, {afa, 0, Pi/6, 0.001}], "Table"];
```

Comment: Please show the output curve.

Comment: I have shown the output curve.

Comment: As tmr(afa) is a function of two integrals, maybe plot each integral function separately to see which one is causing problems.  Also maybe help if you convert all machine-precision vals to arbitrary-precision like switch 0.59 to 59/100.  Then add WorkingPrecision->50 or so to the NIntegrate function or some other explicit working preciison.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Both the two integrals cause the problems. In addtion, I have added the Workingprecision, however, it does not worlk.

Comment: @user59546:  If both integrals cause problems then just focus on getting one without problems first.  Have you converted all constants to arbitrary precision?  Integrate one integral from say 0.2<afa<0.5 with WorkingPreicsion->50.  Do you still obtain the disturbance in the plot?

Comment: I am not sure what causes those spikes but the output has very large values and I saw an hbar that is very small. Perhaps there is some numerical noise because you are using dimensionful quantities that perhaps span different scales. As I remember, in fluid dynamics people usually work with adimensional variables by rescaling everything to prevent numerical issues when working with big or small dimensionful quantities and I believe this is good practice in general.

Comment: Also as @josh said, if the problem is numerical noise, working with arbitrary precision should solve the problem (although it will make the code slower) but you have to change all your constants above to accommodate for the change in WorkingPrecision. That is, you can not have constants that contain numbers like 0.59 or 1.95*10^(-9) as these are machine precision numbers that would render the high precision of WorkingPrecision->50 useless. You have to use 59/100 and 195*10^(-11) which do not have a defined precision (like Sqrt[2]).  Or rescale all your variables as mentioned before.

Comment: I learned recently that the new Mathematica version 13.1 has a function IntegrateChangeVariables which allows you to change variables inside of an integral. Turning the numerical definitions of the constants above to comments, that might make it easier for you to find the right re-scaling for the variables. That function seems to work with Inactive[Integrate] but you can just do Integrate->NIntegrate after the change of variables and then use Activate.

Comment: You could also just implement the change of variables yourself using replacement rules in Mathematica (or by hand if you have simpler initial expressions that generated the expressions you gave here) but having made change of variables rules a few times myself, I recommend you test your change of variables on simpler cases first.